# How to store non-english text?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, python-2.x

I have a text file. It consists of many non-english character. I want to store this file as a number sequences such as ascii.

How can I represent a non-english character?

```
>>> str(ord('x'))
'120'
>>> str(ord('ç'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
>>>
```

Comment: Why do you want to store it as a sequence of numbers?

Comment: To create a dataset for machine learning tecniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to first `decode` it with the proper encoding scheme, them after that you will get the ordinal value of that character, since `ord` return the integer value of *one-character* string:

```
>>> s = 'ç'
>>> s
'\xc3\xa7'
>>> print s
ç
>>> len(s)
2
>>> s.decode('utf-8')
u'\xe7'
>>> len(s.decode('utf-8'))
1
>>> ord(s.decode('utf-8'))
231
```